# Split string (or regex match) at position/index of nth character in Perl?

Tags: regex, string, perl, split

There is a similarly worded question, but I think this is slightly different.

Basically, say I have this string:

"`aa{bb{dccd`"

Here I would like to split the string at the last brace `{`; and have the parts returned as an array. I can easily find the position (0-based index) of this character using `rindex`:

```
perl -e '
$aa="aa{bb{dccd" ;
$ri = rindex($aa, "{") ;
print "$ri\n"; '

5
```

... and given that I'm not a Perl coder, first thing I think of is to use something like <s>`$str = split($aa, 3)`</s>. Unfortunately, that is not correct syntax - [`split`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/split.html) takes a regex as first argument (what to match for), and string as second - and it doesn't take an integer position index as argument.

I found posts like [Perl Guru Forums: Perl Programming Help: Intermediate: split or splice string on char count?](http://perlguru.com/gforum.cgi?post=50399;guest=5386615), which recommend using `substr` in a similar context; however, I'd have to write two `substr`s to populate the list as per the example above, and so I'd rather hear about alternatives to substr.

Basically, if the problem of matching the position of N-th character can be expressed as a regex match, the `split` could work just as well - so that would be my primary question. However, I'd also be interested in hearing if there are Perl built-in functions that could accept a list/array of integers specifying character positions, and return an array containing the split sections.

EDIT:

To summarize the above - I'd like to have the character indexes, because I'd like to print them out for debugging; and at the same time, use them for splitting a string into array - but without using `substr`s.

EDIT2: I just realized that I left something out from the OP -- and that is, that in the problem that I'm working on, I have to first retrieve character indexes (by rindex or otherwise); then I have to do calculations on them (so they may increase, or decrease) - and only then am I supposed to split the string (based on the new index values). It may have been that my original example was too simple, and didn't express this focus on indexes/character positions much (*and not to mention that my first thought of `split` implies character indexes anyways - but I really cannot remember which programming language it came from `:)`*)

Comment: If your question requires something other than my answer, I have no idea what it is.

Comment: Thanks for the comment, @tchrist ; the thing is, it is correct - `unpack` can be used to split into an array with a single line, is built-in, and can accept character index (all that I asked for) - but then, so can `split` itself, with a corresponding regex. So right now I'm not really sure what to accept (_and since this is quite a bit of new and somewhat unexpected info for me, I'm going to wait a bit until I accept an answer, since I really appreciate all of the examples below_). Cheers!

Comment: I was just trying to ascertain whether the edit to your question changed the nature of the question such that it required a different answer.

Comment: Hi @tchrist - I don't think so; I just tried to clarify why the character position, as noted in the title, was important (_and I can see now that the simplicity of the example made it misleading, because indeed - indexes are not necessarily needed to parse that example in Perl_). Once I settle my thoughts, I should probably reedit the question again `:)` Cheers!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You wrote:

> I'd also be interested in hearing if there are Perl built-in functions that could accept a list/array of integers specifying character positions, and return an array containing the split sections.

To create a function that takes a list of offsets and produces a list of substrings with those split positions, convert the offsets to lengths and pass these as an argument to `unpack`.

There’s a `&cut2fmt` function in Chapter 1 of the *Perl Cookbook* that does this very thing.  Here is an excerpt, reproduced here by kind permission of the author:

> > Sometimes you prefer to think of your data as being cut up at specific columns.  For example, you might want to place
> >     cuts right before positions 8, 14, 20, 26, and 30.  Those are the column numbers where each field begins.  Although you could calculate that the proper `unpack` format is `"A7 A6 A6 A6 A4  A*"`, this is too much mental strain for the virtuously lazy Perl programmer.  Let Perl figure it out for you.  Use the `cut2fmt` function below:

```
sub cut2fmt {
      my(@positions) = @_;
      my $template   = '';
      my $lastpos    = 1;
      foreach $place (@positions) {
          $template .= "A" . ($place - $lastpos) . " ";
          $lastpos   = $place;
      }
      $template .= "A*";
      return $template;
  }

  $fmt = cut2fmt(8, 14, 20, 26, 30);
  print "$fmt\n";

  A7 A6 A6 A6 A4 A*
```

So the way you would use that is like this:

```
$fmt = cut2fmt(8, 14, 20, 26, 30);
@list = unpack($fmt, $string);
```

or directly as

```
@list = unpack(cut2fmt(8, 14, 20, 26, 30), $string);
```

I believe this is what you were asking for.

Comment: Many thanks for digging that out, @tchrist - very helpful (_and "too much mental strain" - indeed `:)`_) Cheers!

Comment: Hi @tchrist - now with a clearer head, I'm accepting this answer, as it shows the most generic solution to splitting by index through `unpack`; I'd only like to add that a regex with curly brace operator like [`/.{$ind}(.)/`](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10955218/277826) can also be used as alternative to `unpack`. Many thanks again - cheers!

Answer (score 3):

```
my ($pre, $post) = split /\{(?!.*\{)/s, $s;
```

or

```
my ($pre, $post) = $s =~ /^(.*)\{(.*)/s;
```

The second is probably better.

If you need the index of the `{`, use `length($pre)`. (With the second solution, you could also use `$-[2] - 1`. See `@-` and `@+` in [perlvar](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar.html).)

Comment: Thanks for that, @ikegami - but unfortunately, that doesn't deal with an index; I partially got somewhere, though , in [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10955218/277826). Cheers!

Comment: @sdauu, `length($pre)` gives you the index. Updated node to address this need.

Answer (score 2):

Here are some ways:

```
split /.*\K{/, $str;
split /{(?!.*{)/, $str;
$str =~ /(.*){(.*)/;
```

Use `/regex/s` if the string can span multiple lines.

Comment: Thanks for that, @Qtax - but unfortunately, that doesn't deal with a character index; I partially got somewhere, though , in [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10955218/277826). Cheers!

Comment: @sdaau, what do you mean? This gives tree different working answers to your question *"I would like to split the string at the last brace `{`; and have the parts returned as an array"*, and so does ikegami's answer.

Comment: Thanks for that, @Qtax - indeed, to that question it is an answer; however, I was looking for a way to both keep character positions as delimiters - and use them for splitting a string into array (but without using substr), with something as close as possible to how split behaves (that is, `@array = split (...)`). In my post, I managed to put the index right into split - so that is as close as I got to what I wanted. I tried to clarify the OP, hope it's better now. Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

The way to do this using `rindex` is to employ `substr` to extract the two parts of the string according to the position of the `{`.

Note that this includes the `{` in the suffix part. To exclude it you would use `$i + 1` in the second `substr` call.

```
my $str = "aa{bb{dccd";

my $i = rindex $str, '{';
my $pref = substr $str, 0, $i;
my $suff = substr $str, $i;

print $pref, "\n";
print $suff, "\n";
```

**output**

```
aa{bb
{dccd
```

---

**Update**

I have just read about your wish to avoid `substr` and do the split in a single operation. `unpack` will do that for you, like this

```
my $str = "aa{bb{dccd";

my $i = rindex $str, '{';

my ($pref, $suff) = unpack "A$i A*", $str;

print $pref, "\n";
print $suff, "\n";
```

with identical output to the previous code.

Comment: Thanks for that, @Borodin - but I was actually looking for a way away from `substr`, and closer to the syntax of `split` (_and I did manage to get somewhere in [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10955218/277826), just need to get rid of the blanks `:)`_) Cheers!

Comment: Many thanks for the edit, @Borodin - `unpack` looks very good; accepts the index, one call and returns an array ... Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

I still don't see what's so difficult about this.  Is it that you don't want to discard the brace (or whatever your delimiter is)?  These adaptations of @Qtax's solutions leave the brace in either the first or second substring:

```
# split before the brace
split /.*\K(?=\{)/, $str;
split /(?=\{(?!.*\{))/, $str;
$str =~ /(.*)(\{.*)/;

# split after the brace
split /.*\{\K)/, $str;
split /(?<=\{(?!.*\{))/, $str;
$str =~ /(.*\{)(.*)/;
```

(I know it isn't necessary to escape the brace, but I think it's a little easier to read this way.)

Comment: Thanks for that, @AlanMoore - I tried to clarify better in the OP; I basically take character indexes first (which I used `rindex` for, but now realize I can use a regex for as well, and get index of its matches) - then I do calculations on them - then finally I need to split on the modified values. The expressions in your post, while they do actually perform the parsing properly on the simplified example I provided, do not "accept" an index/position value - which was my original problem (and apologies I didn't clarify that well in my OP). Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

Right, I'll post this as an answer, this is how far I got.

Thanks to these resources:

- [Splitting a string in Perl](http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=682907)
- [Regular Expressions - a Simple User Guide and Tutorial](http://www.zytrax.com/tech/web/regex.htm)

... I learned about the "curly brace" regex operator, `{n}` which '*Matches the preceding character, or character range, n times exactly*'. Thus, I can match for `/.{5}(.)/`:

```
perl -e '
$aa="aa{bb{dccd" ;
$aa =~ /.{5}(.)/  && print "--${1}--\n"; '

--{--
```

this selects through first 5 "any" characters - and then select and print the next one. Or:

```
/               # start regex
 {              # match "{" character
  {5}           # repeat previous five times
     (.)        # select into match group (the $1) next character
        /       # end regex
```

So, finally, I can use the `rindex` to perform such a split:

```
perl -e '
$aa="aa{bb{dccd" ;
$ri = rindex($aa, "{") ;
$aa =~ /.{$ri}(.)/  && print "--${1}--\n";
@res = split(/^.{$ri}(.)/, $aa);
print join("; ", @res) . "\n"; '

--{--
; {; dccd
```

.. but given that also requires some capturing at start, so here are other variants:

```
@res = split(/^(.{$ri})(.)/, $aa);

--{--
; aa{bb; {; dccd


@res = split(/^(.{$ri})./, $aa);

--{--
; aa{bb; dccd
```

... which both would work for me - except I have a blank as first item, which I'd like to get rid of in one pass (without calling extra `splice`), but don't know how to :)

Cheers!

Comment: Your `split` is becoming an awkward way of simply applying a regex. You may as well write `@res = $aa =~ /^(.{$i})(.)(.*)/` or, even better, let the regex engine find the last brace for you with `@res = $str =~ /^(.*)(\{)(.*)/`.

Comment: @Borodin - indeed it is awkward; I guess that I've remembered from somewhere a "split" function that accepts indexes instead of a regex match, and so I tried to bring this one as close as possible to that behavior `:)` The thing is, I didn't know that I can get a reference to an index of a regex match, but comment in [ikegami](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10955128/277826)'s post just mentioned it. Cheers!

Comment: I'm not sure you're aware that you don't *need* an index to the regex match if you just let the regex do the split for you? Do you need an index for another purpose?

Comment: Thanks for that, @Borodin - yes, I was aware that I don't need to specify indexes for regex; and indeed - I would need indexes for a different purpose (_and that is why in this case, I started first thinking about indexes, and then towards parsing; which may have made my question unnecessarily unclear_). Cheers!

Comment: Why does it have to be so complicated. Doesn't `split /(.*){/ ` work well enough?

Comment: Thanks for that, @sin - your snippet works perfect; however, I don't know regex or splitting enough, to have come up with anything like that... hence my stretched-out example up there `:)` Cheers!

Comment: @sdaau - Its no problem. Read about Perl split using regex. What the regex matches in split is not added to the array unless it is in capture parenthesis. If it is, its a new injected element. The other part is `.*`, as others have said, will match everything up to the last }. Had it been `.*?`, it would match up to the first/next }.